# Force return from WaitCommEvent when FTDI VCP COM port is destroyed

Tags: windows, multithreading, events, serial-port, ftdi

I have a thread that handles receive for a COM port using the FTDI VCP (Virtual Com Port) driver.  This thread spends most of its time blocking on WaitCommEvent().  The only event set in the CommMask is EV_RXCHAR.  I am trying to gracefully handle shutting down this event monitoring thread when the user unplugs the VCP device from the USB port and thus destroys the VCP port.  When device is unplugged the thread continues to block on WaitCommEvent().  There is no error return.  I can detect in the main thread that the device has been destroyed but I can't get the event monitor thread to wake up so it will exit.  Under more normal conditions a call to SetCommMask would trigger the thread to unblock but since the VCP port has been destroyed all attempts to use any COMM related calls using the VCP port handle return ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.  The problem is unplugging the device destroys the VCP which makes all COMM related calls unavailable.

A solution I've pondered is if it is possible to have the monitor thread wait on multiple events?  Where one of those events is a comm event and the other is one I create for the purpose of forcing exit.  If so how does one extract the comm event from the comm handle to be given to WaitMultipleEvents()

Another more drastic solution is to use TerminateThread but there are lots of warnings and disclaimers on not using that.

Comment: you not need dedicated thread at all. you not need use blocking call. always use asynchronous calls to `WaitCommEvent` and other serial calls.

Comment: @RbMm I don't see how one could call WaitCommEvent asynchronously.  The point of the call is to block and wait.  The thread that is waiting on EV_RXCHAR event to occur is responsible for processing characters into a buffer.  Use of asynchronous calls would imply a polling operation which is not the desired design.

Comment: *Use of asynchronous calls would imply a polling operation* - no this is absolute wrong. not need any poling. asynchronously always the best way. and call `WaitCommEvent` very easy - you need open asynchronous `FileHandle`, than call `BindIoCompletionCallback` on this handle. allocate data structure, inherited from `OVERLAPPED` (where you need have pointer to your data structure for port). and call `WaitCommEvent` with this pointer. it just return. when event fired - your callback will be called with pointer to `OVERLAPPED` . not need any polling ofcourse

Comment: you not need block and wait. the best - set callback, which will be called exactly when event fired or i/o canceled (due handle closed or CancelIo)

Comment: In what thread context does this callback occur?  Is it running in my main thread context but acting as an interrupt to my code?  Wouldn't I have the a similar issue trying to cancel this I/O if the device has been destroyed and handle is no longer valid?

Comment: if you use `BindIoCompletionCallback` - callback will be called in some worked thread. so in arbitrary context. and in windows not exist "main thread". also user mode code never interrupted. if **last** handle to file object on which I/O request issued closed I/O will be canceled and finished. if no fatal bug kernel driver implementation